# How to get the URL requested in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

So my URL which I am requesting in Django is 127.0.0.1:8000/

I want to get the id no. and URL separately in my views.

I tried using:

```
current_url = request.build_absolute_uri
print(current_url)
```

But it's giving error as:

```
module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'
```

Same goes with:

```
current_url = request.resolver_match.url_name
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Where are you calling this method, can you share the full code? Looks like you're calling it outside of a view instead of from the request object passed to a view

Comment: What is the result you want to have ? show us an example